# Docker build dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image from  dockerfile which I have written.

```
docker build -f ~/www/node-beta.dockerfile
```

This however results in the error:

```
docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker build command always requires a location argument. In this case you should use ~/www/ as the for the location argument, and the file name, "node-beta.dockerfile" for the -f (filename) argument.

```
docker build -f node-beta.dockerfile ~/www
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo docker build -t yee/haw -f ~/www/node-beta.dockerfile ~/www/
```

Comment: ...I think this is a self-answer, shouldn't be a comment or edit.